# tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError'>

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to run the cat and dog example and I got stuck on the input data step. Could someone help me to understand why I'm wrong and help me to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.
ps：I don't really understand why the error is in C:\Users\siqiz\Desktop\tensorflowLearing\01Catsvsdogs\traincat.2893.jpg because all my pictures should be saved like C:\Users\siqiz\Desktop\tensorflowLearing\01Catsvsdogs\train\cat.0.jpg

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BATCH_SIZE = 2
CAPACITY = 256
IMG_W = 208
IMG_H = 208

train_dir = 'C:\\Users\\siqiz\\Desktop\\tensorflowLearing\\01Catsvsdogs\\train\\'

image_list, label_list = get_files(train_dir)
image_batch, label_batch = get_batch(image_list, label_list, IMG_W, IMG_H, BATCH_SIZE, CAPACITY)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    i = 0
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    try:
        while not coord.should_stop() and i<1:

            img, label = sess.run([image_batch, label_batch])

            # just test one batch
            for j in np.arange(BATCH_SIZE):
                print('label: %d' %label[j])
                plt.imshow(img[j,:,:,:])
                plt.show()
            i+=1

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('done!')
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)


def get_batch(image, label, image_W, image_H, batch_size, capacity):
    '''
    Args:
        image: list type
        label: list type
        image_W: image width
        image_H: image height
        batch_size: batch size
        capacity: the maximum elements in queue
    Returns:
        image_batch: 4D tensor [batch_size, width, height, 3], dtype=tf.float32
        label_batch: 1D tensor [batch_size], dtype=tf.int32
    '''

    image = tf.cast(image, tf.string)
    label = tf.cast(label, tf.int32)

    # make an input queue
    input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([image, label])

    label = input_queue[1]
    image_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)

    ######################################
    # data argumentation should go to here
    ######################################

    image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, image_W, image_H)


    image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)

    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label],
                                                batch_size= batch_size,
                                                num_threads= 64, 
                                                capacity = capacity)

    #you can also use shuffle_batch 
#    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image,label],
#                                                      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
#                                                      num_threads=64,
#                                                      capacity=CAPACITY,
#                                                      min_after_dequeue=CAPACITY-1)

    label_batch = tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size])
    image_batch = tf.cast(image_batch, tf.float32)

    return image_batch, label_batch
```

and the error is

```
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError'>, NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:\Users\siqiz\Desktop\tensorflowLearing\01Catsvsdogs\traincat.2893.jpg : ???????????
; No such file or directory
         [[Node: ReadFile = ReadFile[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](input_producer/Gather)]]
Done training -- epoch limit reached
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-0683f80cdbe4>", line 1, in <module>
    run_training()

  File "C:/Users/siqiz/Desktop/tensorflowLearing/newCatAndDogs/01 cats vs dogs/training.py", line 95, in run_training
    coord.join(threads)

  File "C:\Users\siqiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)

  File "C:\Users\siqiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value

  File "C:\Users\siqiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\queue_runner_impl.py", line 252, in _run
    enqueue_callable()

  File "C:\Users\siqiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1259, in _single_operation_run
    None)

  File "C:\Users\siqiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))

NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:\Users\siqiz\Desktop\tensorflowLearing\01Catsvsdogs\traincat.2893.jpg : ???????????
; No such file or directory
     [[Node: ReadFile = ReadFile[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](input_producer/Gather)]]
```

Comment: What about using / instead of \\ ?

Comment: I tried but it's even worse. When I use \\, image_list still can find files like C:\Users\siqiz\Desktop\tensorflowLearing\01Catsvsdogs\train\cat.0.jpg. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, is this question solved?

Comment: No, I tried but failed.

Answer (score 0):

reading carefully for this error:"failed to Create/Open: C:\Users\siqiz\Desktop\tensorflowLearing\01Catsvsdogs\traincat.2893.jpg"
your file name must be the cat.2893.jpg, but here, your computer recognizes the file name is "traincat.2893.jpg".

you can try to delete the "\\" at end of the "train_dir", like that:
train_dir = 'C:\Users\siqiz\Desktop\tensorflowLearing\01Catsvsdogs\train'

I'm not sure it works or not because I didn't study tensorflow on windows, I study tensorflow on Ubuntu.lol

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.